# How to clone/copy an instance of my own class?

Tags: java, deep-copy

Is this way of using `clone` correct? I am getting a runtime error every time. Also can anybody suggest a way to write copy constructor in this class?

```
public class Pair {
    final StringBuffer x;
    final StringBuffer y;

    public Pair(StringBuffer x, StringBuffer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public StringBuffer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public StringBuffer getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Pair clone() {
        Pair p = new Pair(new StringBuffer(), new StringBuffer());
        try {
            p = (Pair) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `arraylist` mentioned in the title and tag?

Comment: Why do you have a copy constructor, when you ignore what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy constructor:

```
public Pair(Pair other) {
  this.x = new StringBuffer(other.x.toString());
  this.y = new StringBuffer(other.y.toString());
}
```

You should [avoid using `clone()`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71):

> - `clone` is very tricky to implement correctly in all circumstances, nearly to the point of being pathological
> - the importance of copying objects will always remain, since object fields often need to be defensively copied
> - copy constructors and static factory methods provide an alternative to clone, and are much easier to implement

Comment: In addition, the native implementation of `clone` will only give you a shallow copy.